# SVG Path - render only a percent of the specified path

Tags: svg

NOTE: I have a feeling that the answers to this question will rely on the dashed stroke trick often used to answer questions about animating svg path  ( e.g. [Animate svg path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33024526/animate-svg-path), and the countless other similar questions). If possible, I am looking for an answer that does not rely on dashed lines.

Suppose you have an SVG with a path between some number of objects. You know where the objects are centered and their width. In principal you could calculate a path that only goes from the the edges of each object. However, this can be tedious. So how can you specify a path form object 1 to object 2, but offset the drawn part so it is only shown from the edges?

In the code below, the first path between two points uses their center. 
This is how I want to specify my path. The second path is how I would like the path to be rendered. e.g. I am looking for some attribute like `offset-from-start=10` and `offset-from-end=10` to do this. If the path is compound or if the object has an irregular shape, calculating the angle of the shorter path is tedious (but straightforward). In addition, using a shorter path, changes curves, where hopefully this offset does not.

```html
<svg style="width:200px;height:200px">
  <circle r="10" cx="10" cy="10" fill="red"></circle>
  <circle r="10" cx="190" cy="10" fill="red" style="opacity:0.5"></circle>
  <path d="M10 10 L 190 10" stroke-width="4" stroke="black"></path>


  <circle r="10" cx="10" cy="50" fill="red"></circle>
  <circle r="10" cx="190" cy="50" fill="red" style="opacity:0.5"></circle>
  <path d="M20 50 L 180 50" stroke-width="4" stroke="black"></path>

</svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to avoid using the `stroke-dasharray` property, how about simply hiding the part of the path that intersects your object? The straightforward way to do this is avoiding partial transparency and drawing the path below:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     style="width:200px;height:50px">
  <path d="M10 10 L 190 10" stroke-width="4" stroke="black"></path>
  <circle r="10" cx="10" cy="10" fill="red"></circle>
  <circle r="10" cx="190" cy="10" fill="#ff8080"></circle>
</svg>
```

A bit more sophisticated would be to define a mask. For that, you need to first define any object inside the `mask` without styling (implicit black) on a white background, and then reuse them with the visual styles:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     style="width:200px;height:50px">
  <mask id="mask" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="white" />
    <circle id="obj1" r="10" cx="10" cy="10" />
    <circle id="obj2" r="10" cx="190" cy="10" />
  </mask>
  <use xlink:href="#obj1" fill="red" />
  <use xlink:href="#obj2" fill="red" opacity="0.5" />
  <path d="M10 10 L 190 10" stroke-width="4" stroke="black" mask="url(#mask)" />
</svg>
```

Comment: I like your approach to answering the question. Unfortunately, partial opacity is required in what I am doing (plus hex opacity values are a pain, although doable). The mask option is nice, but it doesn't scale very well. There is of course the `pathlength` attribute, but that requires calculating distances, and then only draws the path within that distance (no offset), so that doesnt really solve it either.  There are advantages to having the element end inside the object (e.g. for selecting all children within its borders), and mask works with it, but just isnt scalable... anyway +1